# laravel custom helper request

Tags: php, laravel

**Свой helper**:

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers\Support;
class Request extends \Illuminate\Http\Request{}
```

**Контроллер**:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Helpers\Support\Request;
class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function saveFile(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->hasFile('fileName')); /// FALSE
    }
}
```

Когда я использую свой класс, который наследуется от дефолтного, то **hasFile** возвращает **FALSE**
От родного файла все норм - **TRUE**:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function saveFile(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->hasFile('fileName')); /// TRUE
    }
}
```

С чем это связано и что упустил?

Comment: Я думаю что да, упустили. Смотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155500/extend-request-class-in-laravel-5. Без того что там указано, у вас скорее всего будет создаваться объект запроса по умолчанию, хотя не понятно почему его значение будет другим.

Comment: Только "руки дошли", помогло, оформите ответом, пожалуйста! (не знаю, есть ли необходимость, досадно, что другой оформит и получит репу за вас)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю что да, упустили. Смотрите [вопрос и ответы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155500/extend-request-class-in-laravel-5) на англоязычном SO. Без того что там указано, у вас скорее всего будет создаваться объект запроса по умолчанию, хотя не понятно почему его значение будет другим.